Assuming one exists, what is the general algorithm of converting an uncontrolled gate into a controlled one?
A.S.: I'm an amateur, don't be too pedantic.
In a multi-qubit system, it is very easy to pin-point a certain one qubit and apply a given uncontrolled single-qubit gate to it. For example, if I want to apply $H$ (Hadamard) gate to the second qubit in a three-qubit system (without changing the first and the third one), I just take a Kronecker product of gates (in order) $I$, $H$, and $I$ again:
$$
M =
I \otimes H \otimes I =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
{=}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
It's easy to check that this is the correct matrix:
$$
M|010\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|000\rangle - |010\rangle)
$$
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
{=}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
-1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Is there a similar generic algorithm to convert a given uncontrolled single-qubit gate into a controlled multi-qubit gate (number of qubits is given) with one target qubit and one control qubit (both are given)?

For the sake of a concrete example, let's say I have a three-qubit system in this state:
$$
\frac{1}{2}|000\rangle + \frac{i}{2}|011\rangle + \frac{1}{2}|101\rangle - \frac{i}{2}|111\rangle
$$
… and I want to apply $H$ to the third qubit only if the first one is $|1\rangle$:
$$
\frac{1}{2}|000\rangle + \frac{i}{2}|011\rangle + H(\frac{1}{2}|101\rangle) + H(-\frac{i}{2}|111\rangle)
$$
… to get to this state:
$$
\frac{1}{2}|000\rangle + \frac{i}{2}|011\rangle - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}|100\rangle + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}|101\rangle + \frac{i}{2\sqrt{2}}|110\rangle -\frac{i}{2\sqrt{2}}|111\rangle
$$
It would look like this in matrix/vector multiplication form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
i \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
-i \\
\end{bmatrix}
{=}
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
i \\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\
-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
How do I calculate this matrix in general case (assuming it is correct, which I'm not 100% sure it is, because I calculated it by hand)?

If you want to apply the unitary $U$ to qubit $i$ conditioned on the state of qubit $j$, you need to perform the following operation:
$$ CU_{ji} = |0\rangle\langle 0|_j \otimes I_i + |1\rangle\langle 1|_j \otimes U_i .$$
Example:
Say you have a 3-qubit system and you want to apply a controlled $Y$ gate with target on $q_0$ and control on $q_2$. The expression above will then be:
$$ CY_{20} = |0\rangle\langle 0|_2 \otimes I_0 + |1\rangle\langle 1|_2 \otimes Y_0 .$$
The subscripts here are important because we know that $q_1$ does not partake in this operation, so we need to apply an identity to that qubit. So, the complete unitary $\mathcal{U}$ acting on all three qubits will be:
$$ \mathcal{U} = |0\rangle\langle 0| \otimes I \otimes I + |1\rangle\langle 1| \otimes I \otimes Y .$$
This approach generalizes for multi-qubit gates with multi-qubit controls just by replacing $I_i$ and $U_i$ with their multi-qubit counterparts, $|1\rangle\langle 1|_j$ with the tensor of the outer-products of the control state qubits, and $|0\rangle\langle 0|_j$ with the complement of the tensored control state.
Example 2:
4 qubits with a $C\bar{C}Y_{320}$ gate:

$$\mathcal{U} = \underbrace{(|00\rangle\langle 00|+|01\rangle\langle 01| + |11\rangle\langle 11|)}_{\text{complement of ctrl state}}  \otimes I \otimes I +  \underbrace{|10\rangle\langle 10|}_{\text{ctrl state}} \otimes I \otimes Y$$

Thank you! Could you also please add an example to the general case (your last paragraph)? This is the actual case that I wanted to cover (i.e., 1+ target qubits, 0+ control qubits), but I didn't hope to correctly phrase it in the question

Sure. See example 2 above.

Appreciate it. Though, if my understanding is correct, shouldn't $CCY_{320}$ be a Kronecker product of 4 gates? I.e., is one more "$\otimes I$" missing on both sides of $+$?

Ah, I see. We split two qubits from the state into the control and control-complement, and then there are two qubits remaining.
